# Solve an inequality for $x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

From $$((-4x)(x-2)^2(x^2+x-2)+{(x-2)^3(4x^2)(-2))}/{((x^2-5x-6)(8-6x+x^2))>0}$$ I get down to 
$$((-4x)(x-2)(x-1)(x+2)+{(x-2)(x-2)4x^2(-2))}/({(x+1)(x-6)(x-4))>0}$$
and get confused--any help?
Solve for x

Comment: can you use $\LaTeX$ please?

Comment: what must be do with these two terms?

Comment: @Nick Please check your edited question!

Comment: what needs to be done with this expressions?

Comment: is it $$\frac{(-4x)(x-2)(x-1)(x+2)+(x-2)(x-2)4x^2(-2)}{(x+1)(x+6)(x-4)}>0$$?

Comment: yes--thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simplifying the numerator we get $$(-4)(x-2)x(3x^2-3x-2)$$ can you proceed?

Comment: yes thank you for helping